# Как поймать появление div без счетчика

Tags: javascript, jquery

На странице периодически создается div с классом `.ytp-ad-preview-container`.
Как поймать его появление. Хочу добавить несколько функций при его появлении. Решение нужно без использования счетчиков?

Comment: что значит появление? без каких счетчиков?

Comment: Без таймаута никак, если он может появится в любое время

Comment: @АлександрСычёв Спасибо, поправил вопрос

Comment: Хотите рекламу на ютубе заблокировать? :)

Comment: @ΝNL993 Перематывать на скорости х16 без звука

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть такой вот вариант "слежения"...

```js
const node = document.querySelector('#test')
let observer = new MutationObserver(e => {
  console.log(e[0].addedNodes[0].classList.contains('ytp-ad-preview-container'))
})
observer.observe(node, {childList: true})
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', _ => {
  const o = document.createElement('p')
  o.className = 'ytp-ad-preview-container'
  o.textContent = new Date()
  node.appendChild(o)
})
```

```html
<div id='test'></div>
<button>Test</button>
```

Comment: А как же `subtree`? Лучше кстати следить за `document.body`, потому что похоже что тс хочет убрать рекламу на ютубе.

Comment: Это все уже детали...